# Symfony4 returning serialized json repsonse

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony5

I'm looking at a new Symfony5 project , where I'm trying to return a JSON response of some data.

I have a `Project` and a `ProjectItem`

I have the following:

```
// Project.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProjectItem", mappedBy="project")
 */
private $projectItems;


// ProjectItem.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", inversedBy="projectItems")
 */
private $project;
```

I have one Project, that can have many ProjectItems

I then have a controller that I'm trying to return a json response:

```
public function index()
{
    $itemsList = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Project::class)
        ->findAll();

    $items = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($itemsList, 'json');

    return new Response($items, 200);
}
```

This is currently returning an error:

> A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\Project" (configured limit: 1)

Am I using the serializer correctly or are my models incorrectly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use json_encode:

```
public function index()
{
    $itemsList = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Project::class)
    ->findAll();

    return new Response(
        json_encode($itemsList), 
        200
    );
}
```

or use JsonResponse class:

```
return new JsonResponse($itemsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular reference with your relations. Im guessing **ProjectItem** has a field **project** that is referencing **Project** which causes a loop for the serializer. You can ignore said attribute to prevent this from happening. Checkout the [ignored attributes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes) section of the serializer documentation.

Another option would be to use [Serialization Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations). Every property would get a Group annotation like for example `@Groups("group1")` excluding that reference property back to **Project**.
You would then tell the serializer to serialize that group:

```
$json = $serializer->serialize(
    $itemList,
    'json', ['groups' => 'group1']
);
```

You may also checkout [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) which adds @Exclude and @Include [annotations](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) to make this step a bit easier.